# Why are there dotted lines in wireframe in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

I am testing 2.8 and I stumbled over the wireframe.
As you can see the I put a cylinder in between two objects.
The lines being hidden by the other objects are more dotted than solid lines

[image]

In the top-View it is even worse

[image: orthogonal Top]

With overlay disabled it isn't better though

[image: without overlay enabled]

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug or is this feature still not fully implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is will help :

Object mode > Overlays > change the Wireframe value from the default 0.5 to 1.0.

[image]

and toggle the Show whole scene transparent button:

[image]